# AWS ELB allows VPC public v4 IP but not security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-security-group

I am trying to confirm expected behaviour of AWS ELB inbound rules from a EC2 inside a VPC.

test case - all same AWS account

1. add `ec2-A` to `vpc-A` as webservice
2. add `ec2-A` to `elb-A` as target group
3. create `elb-A` security group
4. add `ec2-B` as request source to `vpc-A`
5. add `ec2-B` public IP/32 to `elb-A` security group as inbound access
6. ==> try wget from `ec2-B` via `elb-A` to `ec2-A` = `success`
7. remove `ec2-B` IP/32 from `elb-A` security group
8. add `ec2-B` `securty group` (sg-xxxxxx) to `elb-A` security group
9. ==> try wget from `ec2-B` via `elb-A` to `ec2-A` = `fail`

Is it expected behaviour that an `elb` will allow IP/32 as a source but not the `sg-xxxx` id of the same `ec2` instance? is there anything else I should check?

Comment: Application load balancer or Classic? And how are you accessing the LB: AWS-assigned name, ALIAS record with your own domain, CNAME with your own domain?

Comment: What is the meaning of point 4?